# Area of Triangle when the Areas of Two Smaller Triangles are Given

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

Hello,

Could anyone explain how this solution works because I do not understand why (1+2) is being squared and why the result is being multiplied by 8.

I have included a solution to the question and it would be much appreciated if you could explain why it works.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\triangle PQL$ has twice the area of $\triangle PQN$, with common base $PQ$, so $LP = 2 NP$, and $NL = 3 NP$.

Then $\triangle LMN$ is similar to $\triangle PQN$, but with dimensions increased by a factor of $3$, so the area goes up by a factor of $3^2 = 9$.

Hence, the area of $\triangle LMN$ is $9 \times 8 = 72$, and the area of $\triangle LMQ$ is $72 - 8 - 16 = 48$.

Answer (score 0):

let $x=\overline {NP}$,  $y=\overline {PQ}$, and $z=\overline {PL}$  Then we are told that $8=\frac 12 xy$ and $16=\frac 12 zy$ whence $z=2x$.  Now just use the fact that $\Delta NPQ$ is similar to $\Delta NLM$  to compute the area of $\Delta NLM$ and finally subtract the known areas from the total area to get the desired area.